# How to look up on array of objects and and each object has a different ObjectId of each object

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of profiles in a somecollection. Profile Array looks like

```
profiles:[
{userProfile : ObjectId("5cb9588b6f74784babadd38b")},
{customerProfile : ObjectId("5cb9588b6f74784babadd40b")},
{clientProfile : ObjectId("5cb9588b6f74784babadd78b")},
{adminProfile : ObjectId("5cb9588b6f74784babadd66b")}
]
```

Now I want to look upon every profile collection and get data of every profile in a single profile array.

```
My Desired Output is : 

profiles:[
{userProfile : 
{data of user profile}
 },

{customerProfile : {data of user customerProfile}},

{clientProfile : {data of user clientProfile}},

{adminProfile : {data of user adminProfile}}
]
```

The solution which I tried is to lookup 4 times and the result is not what I expected. 
    Below the code

```
db.getCollection('clients').aggregate([
{                           $lookup            
                                from: 'userProfile ',
                                localField: 'userProfile ',
                                foreignField: '_id',
                                as: 'userProfile '
                            }

},

{                           $lookup            
                                from: 'customerProfile ',
                                localField: 'customerProfile ',
                                foreignField: '_id',
                                as: 'customerProfile '
                            }

},

{                           $lookup            
                                from: 'clientProfile ',
                                localField: 'clientProfile ',
                                foreignField: '_id',
                                as: 'clientProfile '
                            }

},

{                           $lookup            
                                from: 'adminProfile ',
                                localField: 'adminProfile ',
                                foreignField: '_id',
                                as: 'adminProfile '
                            }

}                          
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using mongo version less than 3.6 and want to keep using this lookup syntax you need to unwind your array first:

```
db.getCollection('clients').aggregate([
                                  { $unwind: "$profiles"},
                                    {                           
                                    $lookup: {           
                                    from: 'userProfile ',
                                    localField: 'profiles.userProfile ',
                                    foreignField: '_id',
                                    as: 'userProfile '
                                  }
                            },
                            {                          
                                    $lookup:{            
                                    from: 'customerProfile ',
                                    localField: 'profiles.customerProfile ',
                                    foreignField: '_id',
                                    as: 'customerProfile '
                                   }
                            },
                         {  
                                  $lookup:{          
                                    from: 'clientProfile ',
                                    localField: 'profiles.clientProfile ',
                                    foreignField: '_id',
                                    as: 'clientProfile '
                                }
                           },
                           {     
                                $lookup:{        
                                    from: 'adminProfile ',
                                    localField: 'profiles.adminProfile',
                                    foreignField: '_id',
                                    as: 'adminProfile '
                                }
                            }                          
])
```

However Mongo version 3.6+ has a lookup syntax that can allow you to do all this without unwinding the array and keeping the original structure:

a single lookup would look like this:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: adminProfile,
       let: { profile_ids: "$profiles.adminProfile" },
       pipeline: [ 
          { $match:
             { $expr:
                { $in: [ "$_id",  "$$profile_ids" ] },
             }
          }],
       as: admins
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know the new syntax but it does not comes in profiles array it is coming as a new array of admins like
profiles:[
{userProfile : 
{data of user profile}
 },

{customerProfile : {data of user customerProfile}},

{clientProfile : {data of user clientProfile}},

{adminProfile : {data of user adminProfile}}
],
admins:[{admin profile data}]

Comment: well of course it comes as an array, it brings all the admins,  you can then re-format it how you'd like